# how to record voice in browser and save it into .wav file using php?

Tags: php, wav

my PHP application wants to record users voice in browser and save it as a .Wav file or .mp3 file in local disk.How to do this?

Guide me to get out of this problem...

Thanks & Regards,
P.SARAVANAN

Comment: PHP runs in the server, not the browser.

Comment: yes i am agree with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not PHP. PHP runs on the server. There is however a solution for what you want to do:

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Jetpack/JEP/18

This will only work in firefox. If you need something more universal, you will need flash.

Going the paid route, look at http://www.javasonics.com/

Comment: Everything works fine for javasonics applet. But if you are using it for commercial purpose then you will have to buy it to remove their advertisement(which appears on applet loading).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an open-source project for recording audio using Flash in the browser and PHP (or whatever server-side technology you prefer) on the back-end:

https://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps to doing this:
1) Record the voice on the client
2) Upload the recorded file to server

Since HTML does not allow you to use client resources like the microphone, you will have to use an embedded object which does like Flash, Silverlight, Java Applet, ActiveX etc...

Once it is recorded on the client, you can use either those embedded objects to upload it to your server or use a HTML file upload to do it.