# Flash & PHP library to record sound in browser and save to .wav file?

Tags: php, flash, audio, audio-recording, recording

This question has been previously mentioned on Stack Overflow, but the answers were not helpful. I've looked at [this link](https://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/#The_Server) as well, but it does not allow the user to re-record their sound in case they made an error.

What would be your recommendation?

[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684428/how-to-record-voice-in-browser-and-save-it-into-wav-file-using-php)

Thanks,
Lucas

Comment: Why .wav? Would MP3 or some other compressed format not be much preferable?

Comment: Also can you link to those previous questions and explain *why* they were not helpful?

Comment: oh because I used a wav recorder before, it stuffed up, so I want to keep up the consistency - I don't want files of both types.

Comment: There is one Screen recorder that I know of that captures the users screen (and I think with the option of recording the audio out) and it has to use a Java Applet because flash doesn't have the privileges to access this. You might want to look into Java.

Comment: I think flash will be more preferrable. Can you put it as an answer anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check this link.
http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/create-a-useful-audio-recorder-app-in-actionscript-3/

You can send byte[] of sound to any dynamic server (php for instance) and make file and save the data.

Note that there is one thing missing. Once user will click on record button you will see flash will ask for permission to allow recording in pop-up. So If you have low size flash window you are not gonna see the popup to allow and thus no recording will make.

Also I found it records only in wav not mp3 for personal use I used ffmpeg to convert wav into mp3 in php.